# jQuery Sorting on Multiple factors

Tags: jquery, sorting

Hi i have spent 2 hours looking through SO to find an answer but can't seem to find one, they all sort by 1 factor only here's what i'm trying to do:

Handle sorting of a list of div's by two parameters:

**Parameter 1,** sortId; Each div#result inside div#results-container has a data attribute called sortId this ranges from 0 to 2 (0, 1, 2). Also inside this div there is a p with class name totalPrice.

**Parameter 2,** orderBy: ASC / DESC.

**Buttons:**
I have three buttons that should sort these divs by the sortId attribute so:

Button 1 sorts by sortId 0
Button 2 sorts by sortId 1
Button 3 sorts by sortId 2

Then it should also sort the p.totalPrice ASC then if pushed again sort by DESC but still keeping the order of sortId.

I can get it to sort by Price:

```
value1 = $(a).find('p.totalPrice').text();
value2 = $(b).find('p.totalPrice').text();

value1 = Number(value1.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
value2 = Number(value2.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

result = (value1 < value2 ? -1 : (value1 > value2 ? +1 : 0));
```

I just can't figure out how so do it by the sortId also.

### UPDATE:

I have created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngepj78s/

I'm mostly there just the sorting and most probably less clunky code.

Comment: filter out arrays for each sortID and then run your totalPrice sort on those separately, if I'm understanding your question right; should do what you want. It would help if you made a JSFiddle so we can know exactly what you mean

Comment: @bruchowski - thank you from your comment i have put this together: https://jsfiddle.net/ngepj78s/ It works without the ASC / DESC and also might be clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mnyzs/u86789dk/1/) and it should work as intended now.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-rounded active sort" type="submit" data-sort-id="0">0</button>
<button class="btn btn-rounded inactive sort" type="submit" data-sort-id="1">1</button>
<button class="btn btn-rounded inactive sort" type="submit" data-sort-id="2">2</button>
<div id="results-container">
    <div id="result" data-sort-id="0">
        (id=0)
        <p class="totalPrice">$110.00</p>
    </div>
    <div id="result" data-sort-id="1">
        (id=1)
        <p class="totalPrice">$70.00</p>
    </div>
    <div id="result" data-sort-id="1">
        (id=1)
        <p class="totalPrice">$90.00</p>
    </div>
    <div id="result" data-sort-id="0">
        (id=0)
        <p class="totalPrice">$100.00</p>
    </div>
    <div id="result" data-sort-id="2">
        (id=2)
        <p class="totalPrice">$160.00</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var asc = true;
var currId = 0;
$("button.btn.btn-rounded").on('click', function ()
    {
        $("button.btn.btn-rounded").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
        $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass('active');

        var sortId = $(this).data('sort-id');
        //Needed for sorting preferences
        asc = (currId != sortId ? true : !asc);
        currId = sortId;

        //Generalized function call
        var params = Array();
        params.push(sortId);
        $('.sort').each(function(){
            if(sortId != $(this).data('sort-id')) params.push($(this).data('sort-id'));
        });
        leeSort(params);
    });

    function leeSort(sortIds)
    {
        var array = Array();

        // Get Items by Sort Order
        for (var x = 0; x < sortIds.length; x++)
        {
            var sortId = sortIds[x];
            array[sortId] = $('div#results-container div#result[data-sort-id="' + sortId + '"]').get();
        }

        //console.log(array);

        $('div#results-container').html('');

        for (x = 0; x < sortIds.length; x++)
        {
            var sortId = sortIds[x];
            var sortArray = array[sortId].sort(function(a, b) {
                var oA = $(a).find("p.totalPrice").html().trim().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
                var oB = $(b).find("p.totalPrice").html().trim().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
                if(asc){
                    return oA - oB;
                }else{
                    return oB - oA;
                }
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++)
            {
                $('div#results-container').append($(sortArray[i]));
            }
        }
    }
```

A few things to note, I used 2 variables declared outside your functions to store necessary information about the state of output. The sorting is dependant on these variables and they are modified in the click event.

Also, I generalized your function call. This isn't necessary for changing your sorting preferences but it allows your code to work with more divs.

Thanks,
2mnyzs